# Developing a gui for optimization of image correlation (Matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, optimization, correlation

I am a programming novice (just started using Matlab about a month ago), so I apologize if I am asking a lot.

Basically, I am being asked to:

- Develop an approach for scoring the image match between two images
- Develop a geometric shape program in Matlab to generate synthesis images with a few parameters
- Develop a gui to run global optimization toolbox

I am able to complete the first two tasks. For the first one, I use the function "corr2" to compute the correlation between the two images. 
For the second task, I wrote a program that outputs a shaded red upside down isosceles triangle. Here is the code I wrote:

```
function [ output_args ] = TriangleFit( x,y,m )

% this script finds the vertices of an inverted triangle
% three input, three output

x_2 = (m^2 / (1 + m^2))^(0.5) + x;
y_2 = m * (x_2 - x) + y;
x_3 = -(m^2 / (1 + m^2))^(0.5) + x;
% (x_2 , y_2) = right vertex of triangle
% (x_3 , y_3) = left vertex of triangle
% y_2 = y_3
axis([x_3-2 x_2+2 y-2 y_2+2]);
patch([x x_2 x_3],[y y_2 y_2],'red')
axis off

end
```

I'm stuck on task #3. I am being asked to use the global optimization toolbox to find the best X,Y, and slope combination in order to generate a model triangle image. I am comparing this model image to a random image of an upside down triangle that I found on the internet. I just don't really have any idea how to go about doing this. If any of you guys could assist me, that would be great.

Comment: It should be pointed out that your code above needs some work. I'm unsure if you planned to return any arguments, but you never set the `output_args` variable, so nothing is output from the function.

Comment: Anytime I have to do a MATLAB GUI (as far between as I can make them) I start with this video http://www.mathworks.com/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MATLAB!

To be clear, SO is not the place to get answers on your homework. However, I will recommend that you take a look at [GUIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html), which is the MATLAB GUI-building software. Following these tutorials, it should be relatively simple to add a couple of buttons to call your functions and then plot the results.

You need to defined a couple of things for the toolbox, which I will let you look into on your own. You should define an objective function, which will be maximized when your triangle image matches the image you've been given. I would recommend making a matrix which has values which are 1 or 0 depending on whether or not they are within your triangle and then compare the values in the matrix to the pixels in the image. This function can be fed to the optimization toolbox along with some upper and lower bounds for the variables. The toolbox will run until the images are as equal as possible. I will leave this for you to do (since it's your assignment).

Comment: Pointing them to tutorials is about all you can do for this type of question.